# Calling a JS function with its name and parameters in a string

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have searched for a while now, how to call javascript functions from a string (name of the function and its parameters are stored in a string). I have found much information, such like not to use eval()...

I have found solutions, but i don't get them to work. What do i do wrong?

**Here is the short [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDdjD/1/)**

```
function insertArtikel(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6) {
    alert('Called successfully');
    alert('Param1: ' + param1 + ', Param2: ' + param2 + ', Param3: ' + param3 + ', Param4: ' + param4 + ', Param5: ' + param5 + ', Param6: ' + param6);
}

$('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
    todo = $('#txt1').val();
    params = $('#txt2').val();
    alert('Now calling: '+todo+'('+params+');');
    //Maybe making an array of it:
    //params = params.replace(/'/g, '');
    //params = params.split(',');
    window[todo](params);
});
```

It should run the function "insertArtikel" (textfield1) and give the parameters of textfield2 when clicking the Button. SHOULD..

Thanks for all replies!

EDIT: Thanks to sabof! I not converted the string into an array correctly! Difference:
False: var args = params.replace(/'/g,'').split(',');
Right: var args = params.replace(/'/g,'').split(/, ?/);
Now it works!!!!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: Please click "edit" and add your code directly in the question. You said your fiddle is "short", so what's the problem with putting the code here?

Comment: `params` is a string. You're calling `func('1, 2, 3')`, not `func(1, 2, 3)`. Convert it into an array of arguments and use `func.apply(null, [1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is this:

```
var args = params.replace(/'/g,'').split(/, ?/);
window[todo].apply(null, args);
```

However it won't work in JSFiddle, since JSFiddle auto-wraps the code, and `insertArtikel` is not a global function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  function insertArtikel(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6) {
    alert('Called successfully');
    alert('Param1: ' + param1 + ', Param2: ' + param2 + ', Param3: ' + param3 + ', Param4: ' + param4 + ', Param5: ' + param5 + ', Param6: ' + param6);
  }

  $('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
    todo = $('#txt1').val();
    params = $('#txt2').val();
    alert('Now calling: '+todo+'('+params+');');

    var args = params.replace(/'/g,'').split(/, ?/);
    window[todo].apply(null, args);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works - so the failure was, that i did not convert the params into an array correctly..